# How to create SQL grouped sub totals?

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot, advantage-database-server

I have the following code with shows sales data by month and per sales region:

```
SELECT
   YEAR(date) as MyYear, DAB000.SalesRegion,
   type,
   SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(date) =  1 THEN ROUND(value) END) as jan,
   SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(date) =  2 THEN ROUND(value) END) as feb,
   SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(date) =  3 THEN ROUND(value) END) as mar
   FROM
   (
      SELECT DAB020.*
      FROM
      (SELECT date, 'revenue' as type, value, buart, auf_kumsta,PERSNR FROM "DAB020.ADT"
      UNION ALL
      SELECT date, 'margin' as type, value - (menge*ekp/pe), buart, auf_kumsta,PERSNR FROM "DAB020.ADT"
      ) DAB020
      WHERE buart = 'A' AND auf_kumsta = 'J' AND date >= '2021-01-01'
     ) mysalesdata
     left join "DF030000.DBF" DAB000 on mysalesdata.PERSNR = DAB000.KDNR
 GROUP BY YEAR(date),DAB000.SalesRegion, type
 ORDER BY
    CASE WHEN DAB000.SalesRegion = 2 THEN 0
         WHEN DAB000.SalesRegion = 1 THEN 1
         WHEN DAB000.SalesRegion = 3 THEN 2
         WHEN DAB000.SalesRegion = 4 THEN 3
         WHEN DAB000.SalesRegion = 6 THEN 4
         WHEN DAB000.SalesRegion = 5 THEN 5
         ELSE 6 END, type DESC
```

Thanks to @gordon-linoff for helping with that!

The results look like this:

```
MyYear  SalesRegion type    jan feb mar
2021    2   revenue 12345,00    12345,00    12345,00
2021    2   margin  12345,00    12345,00    12345,00
2021    1   revenue 12345,00    12345,00    12345,00
2021    1   margin  12345,00    12345,00    12345,00
2021    3   revenue 12345,00    12345,00    12345,00
2021    3   margin  12345,00    12345,00    12345,00
2021    4   revenue 12345,00    12345,00    12345,00
```

Using the Case, I manually force the grouping of salesregions. 2-1-3 and 4-6-5.

What I want, is for each grouping (2-1-3 and 4-6-5) is to have a sub-total rows(s).

Like this:

```
MyYear  SalesRegion type    jan feb mar
2021    2   revenue 12345,00    12345,00    12345,00
2021    2   margin  12345,00    12345,00    12345,00
2021    1   revenue 12345,00    12345,00    12345,00
2021    1   margin  12345,00    12345,00    12345,00
2021    3   revenue 12345,00    12345,00    12345,00
2021    3   margin  12345,00    12345,00    12345,00
Subtotal 2-1-3 - revenue    12345,00    12345,00    12345,00
Subtotal 2-1-3 - margin     12345,00    12345,00    12345,00    
2021    4   revenue 12345,00    12345,00    12345,00
.. and so on
```

The problem is, I use Advantage DataBase, and it doesn't have Pivot, Group By Rollup,cube etc or any other useful function that i've been reading about.

So, is there an easy way to add this to my current code, without using such functions?

Comment: Just verify my understanding - do you mean the same Advantage Database server as that described in this link - that shows Aggregation functions ARE available ?

https://devzone.advantagedatabase.com/dz/content.aspx?Key=42&ID=49

Comment: Hi, yes - same database. My comments refered to Advantage not having certain functions like Grouping Sets ( like: https://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-basics/sql-server-grouping-sets/ ). I'm sure that there must be a way to do this without such functions and only using standard Aggregation techniques..... but I don't know how. That's why I'm here :)

Answer (score 0):

Okay - thanks.

So I query this line in your original question

> The problem is, I use Advantage DataBase, and it doesn't have Pivot, Group By Rollup,cube etc or any other useful function that i've been reading about.

The link I sent describes use of group by to build aggregations

If possible - take the original code - Move the case statement out of the order clause to create a new [calculated] column on the end of the DAB000 table - and deploy into a view

**Step 1 - deploy your (granular) sales extract into a standalone view**

- with an additional column showing preference of  ***SalesRegionOrder***

preference

> create view RegionSalesView as SELECT YEAR(DAB020.date) as MyYear,
> DAB000.SalesRegion, **DAB000.SalesRegionOrder** ,    type,    SUM(CASE WHEN
> MONTH(DAB020.date) =  1 THEN ROUND(DAB020.value) END) as jan,
> SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(DAB020.date) =  2 THEN ROUND(DAB020.value) END) as
> feb,    SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(DAB020.date) =  3 THEN ROUND(DAB020.value)
> END) as mar    FROM    (
> SELECT DAB020.*    FROM
> (SELECT ....          ) mysalesdata
> left join (
> select *,     CASE WHEN DAB000.SalesRegion = 2 THEN 0         ... .
> WHEN DAB000.SalesRegion = 5 THEN 5
> ELSE 6 END as ***SalesRegionOrder***
> From "DF030000.DBF" DAB000 ) DAB000 on mysalesdata.PERSNR = DAB000.KDNR  GROUP BY YEAR(DAB020.date),DAB000.SalesRegion,  DAB000.***SalesRegionOrder***, DAB020.type

**Step 2 create and maintain a new custom table GroupRegions**

With meta data describing the exact reporting levels you require

(Expressing here as JSON for brevity, and is illustrative)

```
{ GroupRegions
{GroupRegionsName :'2-1-3',
   {SalesRegion : 2, GroupOrder : 0},
   {SalesRegion : 1, GroupOrder : 1},
   {SalesRegion : 3, GroupOrder : 2}},
{GroupRegionsName : '4',
   {SalesRegion : 4, GroupOrder : 3},
{GroupRegionsName : '6',
   {SalesRegion : 6, GroupOrder : 4},
{GroupRegionsName : '5',
   {SalesRegion : 5, GroupOrder : 5}}}
```

etc.

****Step 3 -- SalesAggregations in its own view****

- Build a new query to draw from the RegionSalesView and GroupRegions- , creating aggregation with the GroupRegions Name.

  create view GroupedRegionSalesView as
  select RegionSalesView.Myyear
  , GroupRegions.GroupRegionName
  , LastRegionOrdered+0.1 as GroupOrder
  , RegionSalesView.type
  , sum(RegionSalesView.jan) as jan
  , sum(RegionSalesView.feb) as feb
  , sum(RegionSalesView.mar) as mar
  from RegionSales
  **inner join GroupRegions on GroupRegions.SalesRegion = RegionSalesView.SalesRegion
  inner join (select GroupRegionName, max(GroupOrder) as LastRegionOrdered
  from GroupRegions  group by GroupRegionName) Orderer
  on Orderer.GroupRegionName = RegionSales.GroupRegionName**
  group by RegionSalesView.Myyear
  , GroupRegions.GroupRegionName
  , RegionSalesView.type
  )

**Step 4 - combine both together**

```
select RegionSalesView.Myyear
 , cast(RegionSalesView.SalesRegion as SalesRegion)
 , cast(GroupRegions.GroupOrder as float) as GroupRegions
 , RegionSalesView.type
 , RegionSalesView.jan
 , RegionSalesView.feb
 , RegionSalesView.mar 
 from RegionSalesView
union
select * from GroupedRegionSalesView 
order by GroupOrder, type
```

Comment: thanks ienerd, I'm gonna tackle this ASAP and will get back to you!

Comment: looks like I cannot create views (I guess only admins can do that) :( any alternative methods I can investigate to get around that?

Comment: Hi egg - as data developers we really need to assert to DBA's that we need (no not need - must have) the correct tools to do the job properly.  With such a constraint placed on you I can only propose you extract the full contents of the tables to text file and use another technology to perform your reporting an analysis - such as SQL Server, even MS Excel or Python?  Are you able to get a compromise from the DBA's to grant you view creation privilege?

Comment: Hi irnerd, thanks for your comments. Long story short, most likely not. Would be easier for me to find an alternative way. Actually right now I basically dump the whole table into Excel using a PowerQuery SQL connection and then work on the data as needed. This task here, was my attempt to replace that whole excel work with a "one-stop-SQL-query". I'm currently learning as I go. I'm sure I can manage it with some SUMs and Grouping etc... and using your code as inspiration....  I just need to work it out :)

Comment: egg, you can create temporary table instead of view. The only difference is that the view definitions are persisted as part of the DB while the definition of temporary tables are transitory per connection. So, instead of CREATE VIEW AS SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE, you can do SELECT ... INTO #whatever FROM ... WHERE.... The in the subsequent queries, you can use the temporary table directly as SELECT ... FROM #whatever myTempTable WHERE ...